# How to animate selected <tr> to top of scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use jQuery to animate a selected row to the top of div with following scrollbar style:

```
#sc {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:450px;
    height:80px;
    overflow:scroll;
}

<div id="sc">
  <table id="myTable" border="1">
    <th style="width:100px;">Camp No</th>
    <th style="width:140px;">Lat</th>
    <th style="width:140px;">long</th>
    <tbody>
      <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
  $('tr.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
  $('tr.' + this.id).addClass('highlighted');

  $('tr.' + this.id).animate({
    scrollTop: $('div')[0].scrollHeight
  }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Are you facing any problems?

Comment: nothing change! I mean the row doesn't animate to top

Comment: Create a jsfiddle and put it in the question.

Comment: here is the  demo http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/6yhP3/1/

Comment: Have you attempted something in doing the animation? Can't see

Comment: what do u mean? I have the same above posted code there.

Comment: Your table has invalid markup. The `th` elements should be in rows, and your rows must contain at least one cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of things I noticed:

1) You may not start a class name with a number (perhaps a more suitable solution would be to use id instead of class to identify the row).

Example using class:

```
$('.C' + this.id).addClass('highlighted');
```

Example with id:

```
$('#' + this.id).addClass('highlighted');
```

2) To get the scrolling to work you need to get the offset for the actual row you want to display.

```
$('#sc').scrollTop( $('.C' + this.id).offset().top);
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6yhP3/5/

Comment: can you please also let me know how to make link between roes and markers?

Comment: I mean if user clicks on Camp No <td> s the related marker info windows opens?

Comment: Never worked much with the Google Maps. I think you need to look into the API documenation about how it is done. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This moves it to the top:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#myTable tr', function (event) {
    $(this).prependTo('#myTable');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6yhP3/9/

Not sure what kind of animation you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, your markup is malformed. You should be surrounding your `<th/>` tags with at least a `<tr/>` and even a `<thead/>` around that row...

```
<div id="sc">
    <table id="myTable"border="1">
        <tr>
            <th style="width:100px;">Camp No</th>
            <th style="width:140px;">Lat</th>
            <th style="width:140px;">long</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

secondly, you don't have any class assigned to that first `<tr/>` which means your call here:

```
$('tr.' + this.id).animate(...)
```

is going to fail to find any tr to animate.